# Using memmove with pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memmove

I searched all over StackOverflow but could not find exactly what I am trying to do. I'd like to copy pointer Items over to pointer COPYTO. Then able to call COPYTO->x.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct JustArray {
    char x[30];
  } JustArray;

int main()
{
    JustArray *Items, *COPYTO;
    char d[10] = "Test";
    Items = malloc(sizeof(Items));
    COPYTO = malloc(sizeof(COPYTO));
    strcpy(&Items->x,d);
    memmove(&COPYTO, Items, sizeof(JustArray));

    printf("Pointer: %p\n", &d);
    printf("Address: %u\n",&d);
    printf("Value: %s\n", Items->x);
    printf("Value: %s\n", COPYTO->x);

    return 0;
}
```

This program compiles but will not run. It have a popup saying: Access violation reading location 0xabababab.

I came from C# and finding C to be incredibly difficult to understand......

Comment: `sizeof(Items)` is the size of the pointer. yeah, there's approx one error per line.

Comment: enable all warnings and start from there.

Comment: `JustArray Items, COPYTO;`, then drop the mallocs, then `strcpy(Items.x,d);` then `memmove(&COPYTO, &Items, sizeof(JustArray));`, that'll be better already

Comment: To be clear, `Items = malloc(sizeof(Items));` ==> `Items = malloc(sizeof(*Items));`

Comment: ...and COPYTO is already a pointer, so it's just memmove(COPYTO, ..., no need for the & there. Ditto with strcpy(&Items->x, ..., since x is already a pointer.

Comment: Ok...guys. I know I am not understanding the concept of pointers and address well. Please show me what my thinking is wrong and why... Keep in mind I came from C# where everything is simplified...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is with this line:

```
memmove(&COPYTO, Items, sizeof(JustArray));
```

`COPYTO` is a pointer. You allocated memory with `malloc` and saved the start of
this memory to `COPYTO`. This address is the destination you want.

The `&`-operator returns the address of a variable, `&COPYTO` returns the
address of the `COPYTO` variable, **not** where it is pointing.

Correct version:

```
memmove(COPYTO, Items, sizeof(JustArray));
```

Another problem is the way you call `malloc`:

```
Items = malloc(sizeof(Items));
COPYTO = malloc(sizeof(COPYTO));
```

`sizeof(expression)` returns the number of bytes that `expression`
needs in memory. `sizeof(Items)` returns the number of bytes that a pointer
needs (because `Item` is a pointer), not the numbers of bytes a `JustArray`-object needs.

Correct version:

```
Items = malloc(sizeof *Items);
COPYTO = malloc(sizeof *COPYTO);
```

Please remember it's a good practice to check for the return value of `malloc` &
friends. If they return `NULL`, there is no more memory available and you should
do some error handling.

Also, for every `malloc` there must be a `free`. At the end of the `printf`s,
please do:

```
free(Items);
free(COPYTO);
```

---

```
strcpy(&Items->x,d);
```

You can rewrite this like this:

```
strcpy(Items->x, d);
```

The reason is that array decay into pointers when passing them to functions and
assigning them to pointers. "Decay" means that it returns the address of the
first element of the array.

For the following array

```
char line[] = "Hello World";
```

these are equivalent:

```
char *ptr1 = &line[0];
char *ptr2 = &(line[0]);
char *ptr3 = line;
```